# Call a classmethod from __init__ without repeating the classname

Tags: python, python-3.x, dry, class-method

I would like to call the classmethod `addInstances` from within `__init__` without repeating the class name `Foo`.

```
class Foo():
    myInstances = {}

    @classmethod
    def addInstance(cls, name, obj):
        cls.myInstances[name]=obj

    def __init__(self, name):
        Foo.addInstance(name, self) # class name "Foo" is repeated

#use the class
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Foo('testName')
    print(Foo.myInstances)
```

The code above does what i expect it to do. However "`Foo`" is repeated.

Replacing the line

```
Foo.addInstance(name, self) # class name "Foo" is repeated
```

with

```
cls.addInstance(name, self)
```

leads to `NameError: name 'cls' is not defined`.

Comment: You can call `self.addInstances(..)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't override *addInstance* as simple method

```
self.addInstance
```

will work too.

Both *cls* and *self* are conventions - unlike C++ *this*, which is standard.

That's why you have to pass them **explicitly** - to classmethods and methods respectively

You may also write

```
self.__class__.addInstance
```

Comment: Note that `self.__class__.addInstance` is slightly different from `self.addInstance`, as the former does not allow a method overridden in a subclass to be called. Use the form that does what you want. The issue here isn't really one of convention, but rather that if there is no *instance* attribute named `addInstance`, Python next tries to find class attributes by that name using the MRO.

Comment: @chepner, I think it's obvious. Just to help OP in overcoming sense of guilt when  using accessing class method through _self_ :-)